Reinforcement Learning and Type 2 Chaos in individual trading?
I learned that RL agents typically underperform in markets due to type 2 chaos (where the market itself is altered because of the actions that the RL agent takes on the market). But how is this unique to RL? Doesn't this apply to literally all forms of trading?
Are their other explanation to why RL agents typically underperform and what are conventional ways of overcoming them?
Thank you!

Hi Dylan: If anything does work, no one is going to announce it, so any claim about underperformance is someone else's take on things. I wouldn't necessarily view it as dogma. I also don't know anything about RL so that could bias this comment !!!!

Ah, that makes sense. Thanks Mark!

You're welcome Dylan. The performance of "different areas of stat arb" is always a very vague and slippery road. It's very difficult to know what really goes on performance wise  because any successful practices-strategies are going to try to fly under the radar.
